# Show that $\sigma(1+p)<1+p+p^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that $\sigma(1+p)<1+p+p^2$, where $p$ is prime.

I know that $\sigma(p^2)=1+p+p^2={p^3-1 \over p-1}$. So this is the same as proving that $\sigma(1+p)<\sigma(p^2)$. I know that $\sigma(p)>p$ for all primes $p$, so $\sigma(1+p)>1+p$ and $\sigma(p^2)>p^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with $p$ being prime.

$\sigma(1+p)$ is the sum of divisors of $1+p$, so it is certainly at most the sum of all natural numbers $\le 1+p$, which is $(p+1)(p+2)/2$, and it is easy to see that this $<1+p+p^2$ as long as $p > 1$.

Comment: That is really clever. I did not consider that $\sigma(1+p)$ was at most the sum of all natural numbers from $1$ to $1+p$. That is definitely true and obvious (to me now). Thank you.